# Prove that $Q$, $S$ and $T$ lie on the same line.

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Let $(C)$ be a circle , and $ABCD$ be a quadrilateral inscribed in $(C)$

Let $P$ be the intersection of $(AD)$ and $(BC)$. And $Q$ the intersection of $(AB)$ and $(CD)$

Let $S$ and $T$ be points in $(C)$ such that $(PS)$ and $(PT)$ are tangents to $(C)$

[image]

this problem can be done by Lahire theorem or projective geometry or polarisation.

But I wanna if there is a simple solution by angle chasing or radical axis

here is what I think we should do :

$$\widehat{OSP}=180-\widehat{OTP}=90$$
so OSPT is cyclic

so the problem reduces itself to prove that Q lies on the radical axis of $(C)$ and the circle where $OSPT$ is inscribed.

N.B: This problem is taken from a preparation test for IMO 2020 in Morocco.

Comment: Is the solution based on poles and polar lines interesting. I have such one.

Comment: I aleady have a solution based on poles nd polar lines , but I'am looking for a an easy solution based in angle chasing or radical axis

Comment: I don not have a solution based in angle chasing,but it is not based on pole and polar lines as well, you interested?

Comment: @StAKmod lemme see and thanks